# crashed out in practice for the Australian grand prix

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, phrase-analysis

An English dictionary gives the following example sentence:

> Schumacher crashed out in practice for the Australian grand prix.

I'd like to know how to parse "crashed out in practice for the Australian grand prix." Does "crashed out" form a unit? Or is "out in practice" a unit?

Some dictionaries define "crash out" as "to lose a game with the result that you have to stop playing in a competition. " Is that definition compatible with how it is used in the OP?

Here's some background info: Schumacher won the race in 2000.

I'd appreciate your comments.

Comment: Related (although not a duplicate) is the [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213877/meaning-crashed-out-in-practice) at ELL.

Comment: In my opinion you can either see "crash out" as a phrasal verb, or simply "crash" as a verb, followed the preposition "out" and then followed by the object of the preposition (which is the thing the person crashed out of). A similar example is "worm out" or "worm out of". Some dictionaries give this as an idiom, whereas other dictionaries simply define "worm" as something like "2. To make one's way by artful or devious means: He can't worm out of this situation. " I'm pretty sure one answer isn't the definitive one to the exclusion of the other. There are many ways to parse these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *crash out* is an example of a *phrasal verb*:

> **phrasal verb**, *n*: an idiomatic phrase consisting of a verb and another element, typically either an adverb, as in *break down*, or a
>   preposition, for example *see to*, or a combination of both, such as
>   *look down on*.

In this case, *crash out* is not used in the usual sense of *[crash out](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/crash-out)*, but as it's more commonly used in motorsports commentary. In this usage, it means that Schumacher damaged his car badly enough in that crash during that practice session that he could no longer take part in it.

Formula One normally has two practice sessions on the Friday of a race weekend, and the race teams can normally repair the car in time for the driver to take part in the rest of the race weekend (a third practice session, and qualifying, on Saturday, and the race on Sunday).

Comment: How do you know "crash out" is motorsports jargon? Any reference?

Comment: @Apollyon Although it sounds like motorsports jargon, and I'd bet most instances of it are in that context, it's not generally true that it's just jargon from that sport: "phrasal verb
If someone crashes out somewhere, they fall asleep where they are because they are very tired or drunk.
[informal]
I just want to crash out on the sofa."

"1. 
a. 
to go to sleep
b. 
to spend the night (in a place)
we crashed out at a friend's place
" Those definitions and quotes are from a Collins-published work and the American Heritage Dictionary.

Comment: @Zebrafish The definitions you quoted are irrelevant to the example in the OP.

Comment: It's not jargon. We know it relates to motorsport because it is talking about a F1 grand prix. Both words have their ordinary meaning - he literally crashed, and as a result he was literally *out* of the practice session.

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising that it's "irrelevant" to the OP's question because I was specifically addressing something particular to your answer, not the OP's question. You said in your answer that the term is motorsport jargon. I only gave examples of ways it's used in non-motorsport contexts, if just to clear any misconceptions a reader might have about that claim.

Comment: @Zebrafish if that's directed at my previous comment, I was responding to the OP's first comment, just under the answer (and it's not my answer). I completely understand why you were pointing out that this expression has more figurative meanings

Comment: @Minty Sorry, it was directed at Apollyon, as they said it wasn't relevant to the question. I just wanted to point out, in case anyone reading this thinks it's motorsport jargon, it's used in other contexts also (which as far as I know aren't uncommon), and gave some some dictionary examples. It may be that it's used more often in motorsport as the crash seems to be more literal (there's an actual car crash involved). Though I'm not sure that this makes it motorsport "jargon".

Comment: @Minty Is the "out" with that meaning combinable with other verbs? I am not talking about established phrasal verbs, but verbs like "to err." Could we say "He erred out of the race," meaning he made a mistake and that put him out of the race?

Comment: @Apollyon It's certainly combinable with "dropped" as in "Jack dropped out of the course" (stopped attending and did not qualify)" and "Jane dropped out of the election" (removed her name voluntarily from the ballot papers). It could also be said to be combinable with "forced" as in "Jane was forced out of the election by press revelations of her criminal past", although this is a much inferior example.

Comment: "drop out" is a phrasal verb. I was thinking why "crash out" with the meaning of "to have a car crash that puts someone out of a practice session" is not listed as a phrasal verb in the dictionary.

Comment: And FYI. some Americans find "crash out" rather odd: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/crashed-out.3584031/

Comment: @Apollyon not really - the meaning of *out* will depend on the verb (and the context). In *crashed out in practice, out* could mean out of the whole event, or just out of the practice session. In *spun out* or *skidded out* it could just mean *off the track*. *erred out* doesn't work - I think it has to be a verb of movement.

Comment: If what you say is right, it seems that "out" can be used freely with many verbs, subject to the movement requirement on verbs. In other words, it is a productive pattern But why do many Americans find the use in the OP odd?

Comment: I'm not convinced they do - more likely the two or three AmE speakers who seem to have commented aren't that familiar with F1, and it doesn't make sense to them that crashing in practice would put you 'out' of anything.

Comment: The key point in the definition of a phrasal verb is that it's an _idiomatic_ phrase.

Comment: I agree completely with this answer, and add this: crashing out like this can also make one think of: screwing things up for oneself.

Comment: Would you say, "He tripped out and wound his leg yesterday in the marathon," meaning that he tripped and had to quit the marathon?

Comment: @Apollyon See [_idiom_](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiom). A phrasal verb is generally _idiomatic_, not a random pairing of a verb and and an adverb or preposition.

Comment: But "crash out" with the meaning in the OP is not listed as a phrasal verb in the dictionary.

Comment: @Apollyon _Crash out_ is an idiom particular to motorsports. (I'm a longtime Formula One fan, I tend to take the phrase for granted.) Dictionaries are unlikely to list all idioms, even one as commonly used as _crash out_.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the phrase "Schumacher crashed out in practice for the Australian grand prix" breaks down to this:

Schumacher + crashed out (wiped out, spun out, knocked out) + in practice...

Crashed out can also have connotation of passing out: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/crash-out
Here is is "PHRASAL VERB [INTRANSITIVE] INFORMAL"

I am, however, taking the context of the Grand Prix to lean towards a "wiped out" interpretation. This would be as seen here:

"[INTRANSITIVE] INFORMAL to fall and have a big crash when you are riding something such as a snowboard or a surfboard."